# Как изменить цвет текста при смене состояния кнопки?

Tags: android

Есть кнопка, которая меняет своё состояние, в зависимости от условия. Мне нужно чтобы она дополнительно меняла цвет текста с "#ECE1DF" на "#000000#. Заранее благодарен!

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/send_button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#ECE1DF"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Активировать"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />
```

**custom_button.xml:**

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
<corners android:radius="14dp"/>

</shape>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
e1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
     }

     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          b1.setEnabled(s.length() >= 6 && s.length() <= 9);
     }

     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827416/how-to-define-colorstatelist-for-textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить фон кнопки программно можно таким способом:

```
((Button)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

ну и дальше вставьте это в блок условия:

```
if(s.length() >= 6 && s.length() <= 9){
((Button)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
}
```

в else добавьте другой цвет например

Comment: В очередной раз огромное Вам спасибо Andrew! Всё работает как нужно.

Comment: @oysho, рад что у вас все получается :)

Comment: Можно тоже самое сделать и вообще без кода, просто через xml

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вы имеете ввиду через селектор?

Comment: @Andrew, да, всё верно)